# simple algebraic problem (related to graph theory)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given $\binom{n}{r} p^{\binom{r}{2}} = 1$, I want to obtain an expression for $r$.

In particular, applying Stirling approximation $$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} (n/e)^n$$ We see that

$$\binom{n}{r} p^{\binom{r}{2}} \sim (2 \pi)^{-1/2} n^{n+1/2} (n-r)^{-n+r-1/2} r^{-r-1/2} p^{r(r-1)/2}$$

So, my aim is to isolate $r$ in:

$$(2 \pi)^{-1/2} n^{n+1/2} (n-r)^{-n+r-1/2} r^{-r-1/2} p^{r(r-1)/2} = 1$$

Setting $b = 1/p$, I know the answer I should get is:

$$r = 2 \log_b n - 2 \log_b \log_b n + 2 \log_b\left(\frac{e}{2}\right) + 1 + o(1)$$

However... I dont know how can I do it. I would be grateful if someone can help me!

(By the way, this is part of Bollobas' proof for the chromatic number of $G(n,p)$ with $p$ constant)

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any condition for $p$? I guess you need an asymptotic when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: In this case, $p$ is a fixed real number: $0 < p < 1$. In particular, it corresponds to the probability of each possible edge of being present in a random graph $G \sim G(n,p)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, we have $0<r\le n$. As a direct result of Stirling's approximation, we have
$$\ln n!=n\ln n-n+\frac12\ln n+O(1)\tag1$$
Take logarithm at $\binom nrp^{\binom r2}=1$, we have
$$\ln\binom nr+\binom r2\ln p=0$$
For $0<p<1$, let $c=-\ln p$, and $b=1/p$, we have $c>0$, therefore $L=\frac c2r(r-1)$
where
$$L=\ln\binom nr$$
We apply a rough approximation at first:
$$L=n\ln n-r\ln r-(n-r)\ln(n-r)+O(n)$$
therefore $L=O(n\log n)$, which results in $r=O(\sqrt{n\log n})=o(n)$.
Now observe more closely
$$L=(n\ln n-n)-(r\ln r-r)-((n-r)\ln(n-r)-(n-r))+O(\log n)$$
and $\ln(n-r)=\ln n+\ln(1-r/n)$, thus
$$L=r\ln n-r\ln r-(n-r)\ln(1-r/n)+O(\log n)$$
therefore $\frac c2(r-1)=O(\log n)$ and $r=O(\log n)$.
Now we apply approximation (1), more exact than the proceding approximations:
\begin{multline}
L=\left(n\ln n-n+\frac12\ln n\right)-\left(r\ln r-r+\frac12\ln r\right)\\
-\left((n-r)\ln(n-r)-(n-r)+\frac 12\ln(n-r)\right)+O(1)
\end{multline}
Simplify it, we get
$$L=r\ln n-r\ln r-(n-r)\ln(1-r/n)-\frac12\ln r-\frac12\ln(1-r/n)+O(1)$$
Notice that $\ln(1-r/n)=-r/n+O(r/n)^2=O(1)$, and we have
$$L=r\ln n-r\ln r+r-\frac12\ln r+O(1)$$
At first, go roughly
$$L=r(\ln n+O(\log r))=r(\ln n+O(\log\log n))$$
thus
$$\frac c2(r-1)=\ln n+O(\log\log n)\implies r=\frac{2\ln n}c+O(\log\log n)$$
then go exactly
$$L=r\ln n-r\ln r+r+O(\log\log n)$$
thus
$$\frac c2(r-1)=\ln n-\ln r+1+O\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}\right)$$
where
\begin{align}
\ln r
&=\ln\left(\frac{2\ln n}c+O(\log log n)\right)\\
&=\ln\left(\frac{2\ln n}c\right)+\ln\left(1+O\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}\right)\right)\\
&=\ln\ln n+\ln 2-\ln c+O\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}\right)
\end{align}
Finally, we have
\begin{align}
r&=\frac{2\ln n}c-\frac{2\ln\ln n}c-\frac{2\ln 2}c+\frac{2\ln c}c+\frac 2c+1+O\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}\right)\\
&=2\log_b c-2\log_b\log_b c+2\log_b\frac e2+1+O\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: @Walkland Some books are suggested. Graham, Knuth, Patashnik: *Concrete Mathematics*; Don Knuth: *The Art of Computer Programming*. All the techniques used here are well-introduced in *Concrete Mathematics*.